# Tool for building packages and dependencies from source on os x

Tags: ros, rosinstall, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying brush the cobwebs off my last from-source build of Jade on my mac - Sierra. I wanted to get the entire turtlebot source (turtlebot_gazebo, _teleop, etc  and its dependencies in a workspace and run a single catkin_make to build

Right now I go to the ROS package wiki, clone a package, build, then clone missing packages and go on... until I'm there. most of the time I'm not!

Any thoughts on a ros tool that helps me pull all source packages and dependencies on mac os?

Any help is  much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254145/tool-for-building-packages-and-dependencies-from-source-on-os-x/) by [fastestindian](https://answers.ros.org/users/29273/fastestindian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2017-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fastestindian](https://answers.ros.org/users/29273/fastestindian/) on 2017-02-08**:
I've tried using rosdep but it crashes with an OSError exception.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-02-08**:
That's not enough information to help, `OSError` is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably want to use `rosinstall_generator`, see: http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator

It will get you the complete list of packages you need, recursively, for a given leaf package by looking at its dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fastestindian](https://answers.ros.org/users/29273/fastestindian/) on 2017-02-08**:
@William $ rosinstall_generator turtle_gazebo --exclude RPP --rosdistro jade
The following not released packages/stacks will be ignored: turtle_gazebo
No packages/stacks left after ignoring not released
Any reason for this? turtle_gazebo is not in my RPP

**Comment by [fastestindian](https://answers.ros.org/users/29273/fastestindian/) on 2017-02-08**:
My bad... typo in package name

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-02-08**:
No worries, that error either means: it's not released, or it's not in your RPP, or it's a typo :)